# what is right way to pass collection id as argument in Shopify hydrogen storefront graphql query?

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api, shopify-hydrogen

I want to get collection details while I have array of collection ids which I got from metaobjects collection list.

I am using this code in loader function

```
const id_= "gid://shopify/Collection/409408995579";
  const collection_id_data = await storefront.query({
    data: {
      "query": COLLECTION_QUERY_ID,
      "variables": {"id": id_,},
    },
  })


const COLLECTION_QUERY_ID = `query GetCollection($id: ID!) {
  collection(id: $id) {
    handle
  }
}`
```

I ALSO TRIED THIS CODE TOO:

```
const id_= "gid://shopify/Collection/409408995579"
  const abcd = await storefront.query({
    query: SINGLE_COLLECTION,
    variables: { id_ },
  });
const SINGLE_COLLECTION = `query ($id_ : ID!) {
  collection(id: $id_) {    
    handle
  }
}`
```

but this cause following error:
***TypeError: string.replace is not a function
at minifyQuery
at Object.query***

libratry versions I am using :

```
    "@remix-run/react": "2.1.0",
    "@shopify/cli": "3.50.0",
    "@shopify/cli-hydrogen": "^6.0.0",
    "@shopify/hydrogen": "^2023.10.0",
    "@shopify/remix-oxygen": "^2.0.0",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
```

What I want to achieve is to get collection details by using its ids which I have in an array. I want to pass ids to query in loop to get all data collections.